# Get facebook direct image from post URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, facebook

I am trying to embed a facebook post image directly into my wordpress HTML page.

Currently the plugin I am using presents the image like so;

[image]

Is there a way to use the link provided, and the ID/meta data/etc I can extract the actual image URL and embed that.

I was thinking maybe a JS script to run, scrape the image and embed them.

Since currently I am using a plugin to quickly set this up for a client I dont have direct facebook dev API.

Answer (score 1):

its can be the solution:
https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-js-sdk/blob/master/get-user-profile-picture.html

how its works:
https://kilianvalkhof.com/2011/javascript/full-size-profile-picture-via-the-facebook-javascript-sdk/

**Also there is a solution which provided by facebook:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/